# Защита COOKIE от подмены

Tags: php, веб-программирование

у меня есть авторизация на сайте через стим. Далее человеку присваиваются его веб права на основе группы. На данный момент данные хранятся в куки в открытом виде.
Каждый раз опрашивать базу не лучший вариант. Хранить часть в сессии тоже не хотелось бы. Как можно еще защититься?

Comment: Хранить данные в сессии (не часть, а все). Ещё можно jwt использовать

Comment: Если именно от подмены, то храните вместе с куки хеш (sha, md5) от ее же данных с какой нибудь солью (которой в самой куке нет)

Comment: @mike но для того чтоб проверить данные все равно прийдется в бд обращаться
я бы с удовольствием работал с сессией, если бы можно было ее использовать сразу же после установки. типо: 
<? $_SESSION["ADMIN"] = 'z'; 
echo  $_SESSION["ADMIN"] ?>

Comment: Зачем ? Получаете куку, вычисляете хеш, сравниваете с тем, что в куке. P.S. под "данные" я имею ввиду конечно те данные, которые хранятся в самой куке

Comment: Каждый раз опрашивать базу не лучший вариант - кто вам это сказал?